# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'word2vec'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Window 10

anaconda v5.0.1 -python v3.6.3 runs

jupyter v4.3.0 -python v3.6.3 runs

on cmd : `C:\User\KRX>python --version` 
And I got > Python 3.5.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.

---

Hi, I had **ModuleNotfoundError: No module named 'word2vec'** after installing 'word2vec' following this procedure below.

---

1.download get-pip.py on https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. On cmd `python get-pip.py`

2.Install gensim in windows

On cmd: `pip install scipy`, 
On cmd: `pip install gensim`

3.Install word2vec

On anaconda prompt: `conda install -c anaconda word2vec`

---

Until then, I had no problem but when I tried to import word2vec on jupyter notebook, I had **ModuleNotfoundError** as I already mentioned above.

I tried to reinstall 'word2vec' but I fell into another error :

**ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'anaconda::tqdm-4.43.0-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\User\KRX\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running 'conda clean --packages' may resolve your problem**

I tried `conda clean --packages` but nothing changed

I also tried `conda update anaconda` and got same error (CondaError : Cannot link a source that does not exist...etc)

ps. This is my first time asking a question so if you need any other details please let me know. I thank y'all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python word2vec not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643004/python-word2vec-not-installing)

Comment: This looks like a typo—possibly by the maintainer of the package. It should be tqdm, not tqda

Comment: Sorry it was my typo. I fixed it thank you!

Comment: Be careful when using pip with Conda, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment. You shouldn't have to worry about the dependencies, `conda create -n my-env word2vec` should be sufficient.