# Pickle with modulenotfound

Tags: python, pickle, gensim

I am trying to reproduce the results from this repository: https://github.com/danielricks/scholar. I do not have Linux and so cannot install the `word2vec` package the code uses, but it's only used for loading a pretrained word2vec model anyway, so Gensim should do the job.

The problem is that the pretrained model used by scholar is stored in a pickle file (provided in the [Readme](https://github.com/danielricks/scholar) under "processed files"), `postagged_wikipedia_for_word2vec_30kn3kv.pkl`.

When I try to open this file I got ModuleNotFoundError `No module named 'word2vec'`. I went inside the pickle file (in Notepad) and changed `word2vec` near the beginning to `gensim.models.word2vec`, but then I got ModuleNotFoundError `No module named 'gensim.models.word2vec'`

I use Windows and so `word2vec` is [not really feasible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643004/python-word2vec-not-installing) to install. That is why I am trying to come up with a way to use Gensim here.

Answer (score 0):

try importing `gensim` in the script in which you are trying to load the pickle object.

When using pickle, it requires you to import dependant modules in the script which loads the pickle, to avoid having to pickle and store the whole module.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to load this module's `pickle` file, based on class objects from whatever `word2vec` package it was using, you'll need to have its same `word2vec` code available.  (The fact that `Gensim` also offers some similar functionality doesn't mean its code is sufficient to unpickle objects based on other code.)

You could try one or more of the following:

- using the larger `.bin` file included with this project, which is likely the data formal that `Gensim`'s `KeyedVectors` class *can* load with `load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=True)`. (What they considered too large to be practical, when this code was created ~5+ years ago, might be no problem on your current machine. You'd likely need to update other lines of code that were using the old `word2vec` code methods as well.)
- switching to Linux - many of the libraries involved in Python text processing & machine-learning are primarily developed, tested, and used on Linux, so you generally have far fewer installation/dependency/configuration problems there
- figure how to install the `word2vec.c` executable on Windows – where the other answer hits a `'bin\word2vec': doesn't exist` error, it's because that native-compiled executable isn't present, and it seems this project's Python `word2vec` module depends on that. Someone somewhere may have figured out how to do that compilation. (The asker you've linked doesn't look like they tried that separate manual step.)